# effective diameter vs overall diameter of multi-strand wire?

Tags: electrical

Is *effective diameter* the outer overall diameter of a 7-strand earth wire, (about 2.1 mm), or the copper-only diameter based on 7 x 1 mm strands. (2.645751 mm) ? 
(Refer to answer on **multi-strand wire inductance**).

Answer (score 1):

Diameter Factor is the ratio of an outer diameter to the diameter of each strand.

It assumes a perfect circle and no insulation.  I looked up the value of D.F. and found it was 3.0 for 6 to 7 strands.

[image]
  However for much larger numbers of strands elliptical wire shape results in fewer strands for a fixed D.F.

"Effective Diameter" must be the equivalent diameter of a single solid conductor.